# place element at the bottom of page and prevent from scrolling using css

Tags: css

I want to place this div at the bottom of the screen, and it should stay at the bottom even when there is a scroll. But now it moves when I scroll:

```
<div style="color:#FFF; position:absolute; bottom:0px;">
<?php
$time_taken=round(getmicrotime()-$time_start,4);
echo"Generated in ".$time_taken." seconds";
?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the `position` to `fixed` and set `top` and `left` properties accordingly.

**[Here is how to create it.](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fixed-footer/)**

Comment: Can someone knock the stackoverflow admin doors to get the 8 mins time wait to accept this answer.

Comment: @Jean: I have knocked the door here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47814/why-8-minutes-time-before-accepting-an-answer

Comment: @Jean, just leave the browser window open for a few minutes and check if there's anything new. Then accept if you still feel the same.